# latexdiff: how to keep the original colored text in the diff.tex version?

Tags: latexdiff

I have a latex documents which contains text in color. 
When I run

```
latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex
```

the diff.tex version do not contains the colors anymore.
How can I keep the original color text in the diff version? How can I make the cancelled text appear in its original color? By default it appears in red.

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 2):

Open the generated diff file, and look for the following lines, which latexdiff inserts in the bottom of the preamble just above \begin{document}

`\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE`

Now simply delete `\protect\color{blue}` from the definition of `\DIFadd` and equivalently for `\DIFdel` and compile.

If this fixes it you can make this permanent by creating your own preamble file (copy/paste the orginal preamble additions by latexdiff into a separate file, make the edit above and save) and the -p option (long form `--preamble-file` ).